# Display and drag view that is on top of other views

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-custom-view

I need to display view which can also be dragged to required place on the screen.This view can be dragged on top of the other views as an overlay.How to achieve this.My layout may looks like the below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

<org.example.MyCustomDrabaleView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
```

Actually i am trying to build a sample library project where in developers can use my  MyCustomDrabaleView view and drag on top of their views.I am struck up in how to get touch events for MyCustomDrabaleView so that when its dragged i can update its view to its new position.

Comment: What is your question or problem?

Comment: And don't just throw tons of code. Please address your ***detailed problem***.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it simple